# How to set quota for CORS preflight requests with AWS API Gateway

Tags: amazon-web-services, cors, aws-api-gateway

I'm building a serverless application with AWS Lambda and API Gateway. In order to prevent DDOS attacks doing a large number of requests costing me lots of money, I've set up a usage plan with a request quota (e.g. 10K requests/month). This requires an API key to be passed as header by callers.

This seemingly works well, but I also need to enable CORS for this service. For that I need to allow for an unauthorized OPTIONS request ("CORS preflight" request) as browsers don't support sending any special header there. But then I can't seem to find a way for enforcing a quota and I'm back to square one: an uncontrolled number of those requests could cost an unforeseeable amount of money. Is there any way to exclude this possibility?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To enforce a quota on OPTIONS requests, create a web ACL in AWS WAF & associate it to a stage of your API in API Gateway. Add a rate-based rule in the web ACL that blocks all OPTIONS requests beyond the rate limit you specify. Rules in web ACLs can be configured specifically for this, as shown below:

[image]
[image]

For a screenshot-guided tutorial of this entire process, see [my blog post](https://harishkm.in/2020/07/08/how-to-enforce-a-quota-on-the-cors-options-method-in-amazon-api-gateway/).

Comment: Thanks a lot for the extensive response. This still would not prevent a _distributed_ DOS attack, though. I take it there's no way to prevent that?

Comment: @Gunnar Say a million bots attack your API. If you could detect that a DDoS attack is underway, would you shut down the entire API for everyone, or would you try to block just the bad actors? Obviously, you don't want to block legitimate customers just because some bad actors decided to play havoc with your API. So the only way to stop a DDoS attack is by blocking traffic from individual IPs. That's exactly how AWS's own automated WAF solution does it too — [AWS WAF Security Automations](https://aws.amazon.com/solutions/implementations/aws-waf-security-automations/).

Comment: Ah, that's a great question, and I should have more clearly specified my use case. This is for a personal project, so in my case I'd indeed rather shut down the entire service for everyone, once reaching a given level of spending. As there's no way to cap spending like that, I looked into limiting requests, and I thought a usage plan would get me there, but then I noticed the OPTIONS loophole. Seems like WAF is as close as it gets to what I'd actually want.

Comment: @Gunnar You can create an AWS budget specific to API Gateway. Have this budget send a notification to an SNS topic. Subscribe a Lambda function to this SNS topic. Shutdown your API from this Lambda function by setting your API's stage's method throttling limits to 0. For a detailed step-by-step guide to implement this entire process, please see [my blog post](https://harishkm.in/2020/07/10/automatically-shutdown-your-api-on-amazon-api-gateway-when-it-breaches-a-certain-spending-threshold/).

Comment: that sounds like a viable approach. Thank you so much, highly appreciating your extensive reply.

Comment: Unauthorized calls are free of charge

Comment: @DominikHelps It's possible for someone to continuously send an unlimited number of HTTP OPTIONS requests to the API. CORS requires that OPTIONS should be unprotected, i.e., no authN & authZ. So **OPTIONS requests will be billed** as the API Gateway returns the stock/mock response of HTTP 200 with CORS headers for every incoming OPTIONS request!

Comment: See my comment in my answer. Do not open up the cors route manually. By the way ACL rules cost 1 dollar per month. Web ACL 5 dollars

Comment: @DominikHelps WAF costs $5 (Web ACL) + $1 (rule) + $0.6 per million requests in Virginia. API Gateway costs $3.5 per million requests in Virginia. In the end, WAF costs less if you're expecting millions of requests (blocked by WAF from reaching the API).

Comment: So in the end you pay for the WAF filtering calls which you would not need to pay anyways because you only pay for authenticated requests (if you not opening up the options route manually)

Answer (score 4):

You are not paying for any unauthorized calls to API-Gateway.
AWS is picking up this charge.
You are paying after the request is authorized and only if it does not exceed your usage plan.

So if somebody is doing a DDOS on your API without authentication it is free of charge.

If somebody is doing a DDOS with a valid api key you will only pay until your usage plan is exceeded.

Find more information [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/api-gateway-pricing.html).

- Requests are not charged for authorization and authentication
  failures.
- Calls to methods that require API keys are not charged when API keys
  are missing or invalid.
- API Gateway-throttled requests are not charged when the request rate
  or burst rate exceeds the preconfigured limits.
- Usage plan-throttled requests are not charged when rate limits or
  quota exceed the preconfigured limits.

So make sure to have authentication enabled on your API and a usage plan in place for all the authenticated requests.

Comment: It's possible for someone to continuously send an unlimited number of HTTP OPTIONS requests to the API. CORS requires that OPTIONS should be unprotected, i.e., no authN & authZ. So **OPTIONS requests will be billed** as the API Gateway returns the stock/mock response of HTTP 200 with CORS headers for every incoming OPTIONS request!

Comment: Hi Harish. Cors is not authenticated thats true. But you do not need to configure an independent CORS Route. See "Configuring CORS for an HTTP API" in the "Amazon API Gateway Developer Guide PDF". By enabling cors API-Gateway will answer to CORS requests and you will only pay if the users is later authenticated. By adding an manuell OPTIONS Route without authentication you can achieve a similar behaviour but I think in this case you will need to pay for the requests. You can still prevent to high cost by a usage plan. But just enabling cors without the manuell route is better

Comment: The [CORS for HTTP API documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/http-api-cors.html) doesn't mention whether preflight requests to the API gateway are free or charged. BTW, [Enabling CORS for a REST API](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/how-to-cors.html) is the same as adding an OPTIONS method manually with a mock backend. API Gateway does the same when you enable CORS through it, as seen [here](https://i.imgur.com/BSfZjJW.png).

Comment: "By enabling cors API-Gateway will answer to CORS requests and you will only pay if the users is later authenticated" -- @DominikHelps, do you have an authoritative source for this, or is this your interpretation? I'd love for this to be the case, but it's not clearly documented unfortunately.

Comment: @Gunnar interpretation of the docs. Cors is a build in feature. As stated in the docs: Requests are not charged for authorization and authentication failures.Calls to methods that require API keys are not charged when API keys are missing or invalid. So if you would get charged for the options call beforehand how would this make sense?

Comment: @DominikHelps I do 100% agree that this would be very desirable, but without clear indication in the official docs it's just a nice hope we have :)

Comment: @Gunnar Let me try to reach out to somebody and if it succeeds to get back with a confirmation. In the meantime you should be good to go with the usage plan variant. No hidden cost can occur this way

Comment: As discussed above, a usage plan won't help with unauthorized CORS preflight requests. Unless they are somehow implicitly covered as you suggested above, but at this point we don't really know whether that's the case or not. Thanks for trying to reach out. It's weird that this isn't documented.